# Siri Shortcuts: menu

Tags: siri, sirishortcuts

I'm testing siri shortcuts at the moment and I'm running into an issue where choosing from a menu does not seem to work. I have added a menu with a number of possible choices, but when using it in e.g. an alert, the value is empty.

[image: example using a menu]

When using a free text field, it works fine.

Comment: what is it that you want 5, 10 and 15 to do? these actions should be "below 5" "below 10" and "below 15", not outside "End Menu". If you want to just have one "run script via SSH", then have the 5,10 and 15 "Set Variable" and call that variable with the run script via SSH. Let me know if this helped. I can post an actual proper answer once I'm very sure of what you want done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a value for each item in the menu.

Place a number box under each number (5, 10, 15) that contains the same number as the corresponding number.

Instead of using a Menu action, you could use a List instead (much better) in the following format.

```
[ List ] -> [Choose from (List)] -> [Chosen Item]
```

Then just link the Chosen item to the input and go from there

If you can't understand my diagram I should be able to send a screenshot of how it should look ;)